# How can I open a PHP file outside of XAMPP folder?

Tags: php, xampp, phpstorm

I'm new in PHP programming.

I installed PhpStorm and XAMPP.
In XAMPP control panel I installed and started Apache and MySQL modules.
In PhpStorm I did these things:

[image]

[image]

My PhpStorm project is in

[image]

I tried to open my project's php file by this

[image]

the result is:

[image]

Is there any way to make the IDE PhpStorm correctly open the php file from it's project's folder or I have to create every new project directly in XAMPP folder?

Comment: A web server (such as XAMPP's apache) has a document root where all publicly available files should reside. There are ways to specify the path to that document root (and by default it's the `htdocs` folder in your xampp installation path), but why don't you just put your projects in that folder instead? That's way simpler and straight-forward.

Comment: Yes, the Deployment - make sure that 1) it is fully set up; 2) you have no warnings on "Mappings" tab; 3) You did the actual deployment (files were copied there before hitting the Run / Open in Browser button). To avoid that you can setup auto-deployment (so it runs deployment on file save) ... or as suggested by the comment above (Constantin Groß) -- keep you project files right there in the XAMPP root and not in a separate place (so you do not need to have 2 copied of them). Another option: configure XAMPP (Apache) to use a separate (virtual) host so it can serve them from another place.

Comment: You can also add a virtual host in Apache to define another place to hold website files but if you're just starting out, it probably makes more sense to just use the defaults until you're comfortable with the environment

Comment: @ConstantinGroß I'm new in php programming and wanted to know can I put the php file to another folders, not in xampp or not? Why it is interesting to me? Cause It's will more simple to create a project wherever I want and run it from IDE without fear of getting the error which I've got now.  That's not very necessary, I just want to know the ways to do it (if that ways exists).

Comment: @LazyOne I'm not sure that I understood you. What you mean by third point? You mean I must manually copy the files to deployment path or I must make PhpStorm IDE to that automatically? I tried to set the deployment path to XAMPP folder, saved changes and clicked Ctrl+S in IDE. I went to the folder of XAMPP, but  I didn't find the project file there. As I thought, it must create the duplicate file but in fact it didn't.

Comment: Having to configure the path to each project in your Apache's config (as mentioned in another comment, using virtual hosts) for each new project is definitely not easier than just using it the default way. I don't think it's worth the trouble, but that's just my two cents...

Comment: @ConstantinGroß Ok. Thank you very much. I'll vote for your answer. Here.

Comment: @RubenKubalyan The deployment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/deploying-applications.html. P.S. I suggest to keep the project where you want and configure XAMPP (Apache) to serve files from that location instead (using `VirtualHost` .. and a fake DNS name .. or custom port if you prefer using `localhost` only). I'm not using XAMPP so cannot give you the exact steps, but have a look here as your starting point: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/installing-an-amp-package.html#integrating-xampp